# How to reduce Android service restart time?

Tags: android, android-service

I know Android service will restart if I return `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` in onStartCommand

I wrote a service and want to keep it alive after user close the app in recent list

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

After my testing, my service will be killed if user close the app in recent list

Since the `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`, Android will auto restart the service, but the time is too long

Some time the service will restart within 20 seconds, some time will restart over one minute, how can I reduce this time? it is better within 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code inside of your Service class. This restart service when app is cleared by user. And you can return START_STICKY to onstartCommand method.

```
@Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
        intent2.setPackage(this.getPackageName());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService((Context)this.getApplicationContext(), (int)1, (Intent)intent2,0);
        ((AlarmManager)this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE)).set(3, 500 + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), pendingIntent);
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }
```

Comment: `onTaskRemoved()` isn't guaranteed to be called, although it rarely happens.

Comment: In my case, it is always called. In your case what happens?

Comment: Have you tested it on all `Android` devices with different API versions??? I talked about the general case, not a particular one with the only device tested.